# "The result of a delegate init call must be immediately returned or assigned to 'self'" when calling initWithNibName

Tags: objective-c

For some reason, I can't call the `initWithNibName` method with getting the error message: "The result of a delegate init call must be immediately returned or assigned to 'self'".  Is this some ARC perk, because without specifying the nib name, I can't initialize the view.

Here is my code in the `.m` file:

```
#import "SimpleMotionControllerIntroduction.h"

@implementation SimpleMotionControllerIntroduction

-(id) init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self)
    {
        [self initWithNibName:@"SimpleMotionIntroductionView" bundle:nil];
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

I feel like I'm making some sort of a careless error, I've worked with iOS 5 before, and made an app just like this that worked the same way.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two careless errors: you are calling two init methods (1) and you are ignoring the result from the second (2, triggers the error message).

You should never have two `init` calls for one object. Note that `initWithNibName` calls `init`, too. I think this would actually result in an endless recursion and eventually stack overflow.

Answer (score 4):

Change it to:

```
 self = [super initWithNibName:@"SimpleMotionIntroductionView" bundle:nil];

 if (self)
 {
      //custom initialization
 }

 return self;
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be `self = [super initWithNibName:]?`

Answer (score 4):

If your bare `-init` is not doing any setup itself, but just deferring to another initializer, it should look like this:

```
-(id) init
{
    return [self initWithNibName:@"SimpleMotionIntroductionView" bundle:nil];
}
```

As it stands, you're doing two things wrong: throwing away the result of `initWithNibName:bundle:`, and re-initializing your object (because `initWithNibName:bundle:` will itself call up to `[super init]`). The first is the cause of the error message.

Only *one* initializer in a class should call up -- this is the ["designated initializer"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MultipleInitializers.html). Every other initializer should call through to that one.